# Python Function with arbitrary parenthesis (and arguments)

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want something like this

```
def Print(Something):

    print all in Something

Print("This")

Print("This")("Also")("This")
```

output should be :

```
This

This Also This
```

No matter how many parenthesis or arguments are there it should show all the arguments.

Comment: I'm guessing you just want to `return Print` although this sounds like you're trying to introduce a code smell. Why do you want this?

Comment: Do you want the function to accept multiple sets of parenthesis as as many sets of arguments?!

Comment: how to return Print and know where to end recursion..

Comment: yes thats the point .. I want a function that takes multiple sets of parenthesis and combine all of its arguments

Comment: @MubasharSidhu Ok then, see Lukasz answer bellow.

Comment: I didn't say anything about recursion, *why* do you want this?

Answer (score 4):

Bind `Print` name to instance with described behavior, use it afterwards.

```
class MagicPrint(object):
    def __call__(self, arg):
        print arg,
        return self

Print = MagicPrint()

Print("a")
Print("a")("b")("c")
```

Note that there's absolute no reason to do it in real code, where you can do:

```
from __future__ import print_function
print("a", "b", "c")
```

Comment: This is the hackyest thing I've seen all week.

Comment: But why have the class? I don't see any reason for it.

Comment: Brilliant ... but ..is there any chance I can do it without making a class...

Comment: @RemcoGerlich because I wasn't smart enough to realize in this case chaining is stateless.

Comment: @MubasharSidhu see Remco's answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason to use a class here at all, simply:

```
def Print(something):
    print something
    return Print
```

works fine as well.